# Chrome doesn't play my embed file, the request to audio file gets "canceled"

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

I have a page which uses jQuery to play sound whenever users make an error.

Here is part of my html:

```
<embed id="beepCache" src="sound/beep.wav" autostart="false" type ="audio/x-wav" width="0" height="0" hidden="hidden" /><!-- Just for caching! -->
```

I use that just to locally cache the file, so it plays instantly.
This is my jQuery function which plays the sound. It simply adds and the removes the embed element in the DOM.

```
function playSound() {
            $('body').append('<embed id="beep" width="0" height="0"  type ="audio/x-wav" src="sound/beep.wav" autostart="true" hidden="hidden">');
            //wait 1 sec than remove the embed element
            setTimeout(function() {
                $('#beep').remove();
            }, 1000);
        }
```

So this code works in IE, FF and Opera, but it USED to work in Chrome.
When it worked I noticed that all the GET request to the beep.wav were cache hits.

However now I get the status (canceled). I thought that Chrome is TOO smart and it notices that the embed element will be removed, so it cancels the request for the resource, but that is not the case, because even the embed element which I use for caching and is NEVER removed also gets status (canceled) - this happens on page load.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Sorry. It was vlc plug-in which I installed at home.
Since I am using the same Google account on my home and work PC, it got installed on my work PC too.

So I disabled it and it works as a charm again :P